# PHP File Upload Not Working after change to PHP settings

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a simple PHP file upload script to upload files. It was working fine, but after a change to PHP settings, the script is not uploading files, although I dont get any error and it says it was uploaded successfully. The script seems to be doing its job, but I cant see any files in my uploads folder. Nothing is changed in script since it was working other than a change in php settings where I had to request my host to do following the following PHP settings:

```
max_execution_time 60
memory_limit 128M
post_max_size 32M
upload_max_filesize 32M
allow_url_fopen = On (this was the last change, which I believe is the causing the issue).
```

Here is my upload script:

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = "uploads/";
$fileupload = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;
$targetFile =  $targetPath. $fileupload;
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

Note: I am not trying to upload a huge file, Like I said, the script doesn't through any error, but I cant see the files in my uploads folder.

I am not even sure if this is because of my PHP settings changes. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: try removing the / from $storeFolder and remove this dirname( __FILE__ )

Comment: Why did you add `allow_url_fopen`? What's your intention and did it serve your purpose else why not go without it? *just asking*

Comment: @OmniPotens The domain name I am using is hosting multiple demo websites. one of the sites is using a ThemeForest template and some of its builtin plugins requires the allow_url_fopen to be on in order to work. I will move the site to a different domain today and will see if it works. So far no luck with fixing.

Comment: When you've done so and tested and still have issues then you can come around and let's work to see how to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you setting are right but you have error in your php code, line where you are specifing your directory to store the file. You can go with simple

```
$storeFolder = "uploads/";
$fileupload = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$targetFile =  $storeFolder.$fileupload;
if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)){
    echo 'file uploaded' ;
else
    echo 'file not uploaded';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it should be:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.basename($_FILES['file']['name']));
```